# How to convert a string to uppercase using a Queue?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, ide, queue

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<string> // probally not needed
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
queue <string> str; // i created some kind of vector queue
cout << "Please enter a string." << endl;
string temp; 
cin >> temp; // grabs the string
if(temp != "") // checks if string is empty
{
 str.push(temp); // pushes it onto queue
 for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) // suppose to go through 
 //each element in queue
    {
       //str.pop(temp); /pops an element as requied by assignment
        toupper(i); // suppose to turn each letter upper case
    }
}
else 
{
    exit(0); // exits the program if string is empty
}
cout << temp; // suppose to display queue, that should be in 
//upper case form.

return 0;
}
```

I'm still fairly new to programming and I don't know to implement a queue into a string. The problem is the for loop isn't going through each letter, so they can't be put in upper case by the (toUpper()).

Prompt: "Write a program that gets a sentence (string) from a user and puts it into a queue of characters. The program should then dequeue each character, convert it to uppercase and store the result as a sentence (string). Print the result of this process".

Comment: A "queue of characters" is `queue<char>`, not `queue<string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this following way.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<string> // probally not needed
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    queue <char> str; //make it char queue
    cout << "Please enter a string." << endl;
    string temp, result = ""; 
    getline (cin, temp); //grabs string, including spaces
    if(temp != "") // checks if string is empty
    {
        // push each character into queue
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) // suppose to go through 
        {
            str.push(temp[i]);
        }
        while(!str.empty()) //take a char from queue and do the task pop them.
        {
            char tm = str.front();
            str.pop();
            tm = tm-32; // making lower to upper
            result = result+tm;
        }
         
    }
    else 
    {
        exit(0); // exits the program if string is empty
    }
    cout << result; // suppose to display queue, that should be in 
    //upper case form.
    
    return 0;
}
```